# How does attribute mapping in AWS SSO apps work with Azure usernames?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-sso

I am creating an EUC Dashboard in AWS by following this [tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/de/getting-started/hands-on/euc-dashboard/). To log in to the dashboard, you're supposed to link SSO and Cognito. Unfortunately, my environment differs from the one in the Tutorial:

My user management runs on Microsoft Azure and AWS SSO checks Azure for authentication. The users only have a username (in the form of an email), not an email. In the tutorial, (at Module 2, Step 4, §18) Attribute Mapping for the SSO Application gets done with mapping ${user.email} to this schema `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress`.

I instead want to map my usernames.

I have read through the AWS documentation for attribute mappings but that isn't enough for me to work this out.

How do I make this work for my setup?

Comment: Are your usernames emails in Azure? Or some variation of first name second name etc.?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary My usernames are emails.

Comment: Proceed as normal, the `emailaddress` claim will work if your usernames are email - just change the mapping to `user.username` etc.

Comment: Okey that seems like a good solution. I am still getting 403 errors when trying to open the created dashboard but I just might have missed a setting.

Comment: Yes that'll be different :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your usernames are in an email format, you can still use the `emailaddress` claim [schema](http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress) for your user attribute mapping - they'll be no issues.

The only note is to ensure that the correct field is used for mapping e.g. `${user.username}` in this case instead of `${user.email}`.